# error : self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it needs to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement

Tags: rust

i have a struct like this

```rust
pub struct CmdRequestBuilder {
    pub method: String,
    pub url: String,
    pub query: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub body: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub headers: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub include_headers: bool,
    pub include_body: bool,
    pub status: i8,
}
```

as you can see the headers attribute a vector of strings and when i want to loop over it i face an error (bellow)

```rust
    pub fn build(&self) -> reqwest::RequestBuilder {

        let mut header_map = HeaderMap::new();
        let mut builder = reqwest::Client::new().request(self.get_method(), self.url.as_str());

             // error  here  
             let headers = self.headers.as_ref().unwrap();
             headers.into_iter().for_each(|header| {
                let mut header_split = header.split(":");
                let key = header_split.next().unwrap();
                let value = header_split.next().unwrap();
                let k = reqwest::header::HeaderName::from_static(key);
                header_map.insert(k, value.parse().unwrap());
            });
        
        builder = builder.headers(header_map);

    builder
   }
```

> error : `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Yours is missing `use`, the `impl CmdRequestBuilder` block and the `.get_method()` function.

Comment: @finomnis look at my answer

Comment: That shouldn't be an answer, please put it in your question instead. Also, I think you forgot `crate::parser`. Please test your code on https://play.rust-lang.org/ to see if it behaves as expected, before posting it.

Comment: And, after testing it on the playground, you can directly include the link in your question. That way, someone who understands right away where the error is can provide you with the correct code in a blink of an eye, and someone who doesn't can experiment a bit very easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first question is: Will `CmdRequestBuilder::build()` be called more than once on a single object?

I suspect that the answer is "no", and therefore the first fix would be to make `build` *consume* `self` instead of borrowing it.

There are a couple more things wrong with your code:

```rust
// `headers` is a reference.
// I am uncertain why you want this do be a reference, though.
let headers = self.headers.as_ref().unwrap();

// `into_iter()` consumes `headers`.
// Which is impossible the way it is written right now, as
// references cannot be consumed. You need an owned object for that.
headers.into_iter().for_each(|header| {
    // .split creates (temporary) references
    let mut header_split = header.split(":");
    let key = header_split.next().unwrap();
    let value = header_split.next().unwrap();
    // from_static requires static references, not temporary ones
    let k = reqwest::header::HeaderName::from_static(key);
    header_map.insert(k, value.parse().unwrap());
});
```

---

### Solution

- change `&self` to `self`
- fix `as_ref()` and `into_iter()` by removing `as_ref()`
- make the header names static. This one is a little trickier, because I'm quite certain that the values aren't static; so it would be easiest to split `headers` into key and value pairs. Whether you use `Vec<(&'static str, String)>` or `HashMap<&'static str, String>` depends on your preference, I'll go with the `HashMap`.

This is probably what you wanted:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use reqwest::header::HeaderMap;
use reqwest::Method;

pub struct CmdRequestBuilder {
    pub method: String,
    pub url: String,
    pub query: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub body: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub headers: Option<HashMap<&'static str, String>>,
    pub include_headers: bool,
    pub include_body: bool,
    pub status: i8,
}

impl CmdRequestBuilder {
    fn get_method(&self) -> Method {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> reqwest::RequestBuilder {
        let mut header_map = HeaderMap::new();
        let mut builder = reqwest::Client::new().request(self.get_method(), self.url.as_str());

        // error  here
        let headers = self.headers.unwrap();
        headers.into_iter().for_each(|(key, value)| {
            header_map.insert(key, value.parse().unwrap());
        });

        builder = builder.headers(header_map);

        builder
    }
}
```

There will be other problems that you will have to solve now that `headers` is an `Option<HashMap<&'static str, String>>`, but one step at a time.

---

If you *don't* want to consume `self` in `build()`, then you could write this instead:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use reqwest::header::HeaderMap;
use reqwest::Method;

pub struct CmdRequestBuilder {
    pub method: String,
    pub url: String,
    pub query: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub body: Option<Vec<String>>,
    pub headers: Option<HashMap<&'static str, String>>,
    pub include_headers: bool,
    pub include_body: bool,
    pub status: i8,
}

impl CmdRequestBuilder {
    fn get_method(&self) -> Method {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn build(&self) -> reqwest::RequestBuilder {
        let mut header_map = HeaderMap::new();
        let mut builder = reqwest::Client::new().request(self.get_method(), self.url.as_str());

        // error  here
        let headers = self.headers.as_ref().unwrap();
        headers.iter().for_each(|(key, value)| {
            header_map.insert(*key, value.parse().unwrap());
        });

        builder = builder.headers(header_map);

        builder
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to include a `&'static str` in your `headers` member, then the answer is: what you are trying to do is impossible.

There simply is no way to convert a `String` into a `&'static str`. `&'static str` means the variable is available for the entire program duration, which `String` by definition isn't.

Comment: you just made my day